# How would I pass values of a constructor to touch methods?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, prototype, instance

I have an Object that called `vars` and it belongs to a `jQuery plugin function`. The `vars` object contains bunch of HTML DOM classes for using inside of the class scope. My expectation is to pass the object into the class and could access it no matter where it has been called from the scope.

Passing the `vars` to a new class `Proto` works fine. The problem is when I try to get the `vars` from a nested function, it doesn't work (esp `touch methods` in my case). The `vars` can be only accessed through the `constructor` and the `instance methods`.

This is the code:

```js
(function ($, window, undefined) {
  $.fn.plugin = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      const that = $(this);
      const vars = {
        thatItem : 'thatItem'
        // ...
      }
      var Proto = new className(options, vars);
      Proto.exe(that);
    })
    // ...
  }
  class className {
    constructor(options, globals) {
      const defaults = {
        value: 'this is a value'
      }
      this.options = Object.assign(defaults, options);
      this.globals = globals;
      console.log(this.globals, 'can be called using this keyword. works fine.');
    }
    exe(that) {
      that.on({
        touchstart:this.istouchStart,
        touchmove:this.istouchMove,
        touchend:this.istouchEnd
      })
    }
    istouchStart(e) {
      this.coordX = e.touches[0].clientX;
      this.coordY = e.touches[0].clientY;
      return this.coordX, this.coordY;
    }
    istouchMove(e) {
      let dx = e.touches[0].clientX,
          dy = e.touches[0].clientY,
          dist = Math.sqrt(dx + this.coordX);
    }
    istouchEnd(e) {
      var dist = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.coordX;
      if (dist > 200) {
        console.log(this.globals, "It doesn't work inside of the touch event.");
      } else if (dist < -200) {
      } else {
      }
      console.log(dist);
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
$('.inline-grid').plugin({})
```

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      html, body
      {
        background-color: black;
      }
      div {
        position: relative;
      }
      .inline-grid {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 560px;
        border: 7px solid teal;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
      }
      .cell {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
      }
      .orange {
        background-color: orange;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="slider" class="inline-grid">
      <div class="wrap">
        <a href="#" class="cell orange">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell blue">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell crimson">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell green">

        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've changed `istouchEnd(e)` to `istouchEnd(globals)` for giving the `vars` as the parameter directly. And I used `return` keyword to pass the `event` but this way also didn't work.

```
istouchEnd(globals) {
  return function(e) {
    var dist = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.coordX;
    if (dist > 200) {
      console.log(this.globals, "It doesn't work when this.globals are inside of the nested function.");
    } else if (dist < -200) {
    } else {
    }
    console.log(dist);

  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

How would I get the `vars` in the nested functions?

=============== Question Updated ===============

first try:

```
 exe(that) {
  that.on({
    touchstart: (e) => {
      this.coordX = e.touches[0].clientX;
      this.coordY = e.touches[0].clientY;
      return this.coordX, this.coordY;
    },
    touchmove: (e) => {
      let dx = e.touches[0].clientX,
          dy = e.touches[0].clientY,
          dist = Math.sqrt(dx + this.coordX);
      console.log('test');
    },
    touchend: (globals) => {
      return function(e) {
        var dist = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.coordX;
        if (dist > 200) {
          console.log(this.globals, "It doesn't work inside of the touch event.");
        } else if (dist < -200) {
        } else {
        }
        console.log(dist);
        e.stopPropagation();

      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: With `touchend:this.istouchEnd`, the handler loses its calling context of `this`. Use `.bind` or an arrow function

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've tried it just right now but it didn't work. the `touchend` still doesn't respond. I will update my question for showing what I've done.

Comment: Your `return function(e) {` is still a full-fledged `function`, so the `this` is not the same as in the outer scope. Use, eg, `touchend: () => this.istouchEnd()`

Comment: Thank you for advice @CertainPerformance. I should've given the `globals` as the parameter into the `exe` function. After I fixed that, `touchend: (e) => this.istouchEnd(e, globals)` this way works.